# What is the explicit expression of the operator norm of $A$ : $(\mathbb{R}^n, |\cdot |_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^m, |\cdot |_{\infty}) $

Tags: matrices, matrix-norms

What is the explicit expression of the operator norm of $A$ : $(\mathbb{R}^n, |\cdot |_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^m, |\cdot |_{\infty})  $ ?

I have no idea that what is "explicit expression" means, and what I should work on it? All I know is just the definition of matrix norm...

$$ \max_{|x|=1} |Ax|_{\infty} = \max_i \sum^n_{j=1} |a_{ij}x_{ij}| = \max_i \sum^n_{j=1} |a_{ij}| |x_{ij}| $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $y = Ax$ you have
$$ 
  \| y \|_\infty = \max_j \left| \sum_{k=1}^n a_{jk} x_k \right| 
 \le  \max_j \sum_{k=1}^n |a_{jk} | \, | x_k | \\
 \le \left(\max_{j, k} |a_{jk} | \right) \sum_{k=1}^n | x_k |
 = \left(\max_{j, k} |a_{jk} | \right) \| x \|_1  \tag 1
$$
It follows that for the norm $\|A\|$ of the operator
$A : (\mathbb{R}^n, \|\cdot \|_1) \rightarrow (\mathbb{R}^m, \|\cdot |\|_{\infty})$ you have
$$
  \|A\| = \max_{ \| x \|_1 = 1} \| Ax \|_\infty \le 
  \max_{j, k} |a_{jk} | \, . \tag 2
$$
Now $ \max_{j, k} |a_{jk} | = |a_{J, K}|$ for some index pair  $(J,K)$. For the vector 
$$
   x = (0, \dots, 0, 1, 0, \dots, 0)^T
$$
which has a one at the $K^\text{th}$ component, equality holds in $(1)$
and therefore also in $(2)$.
So $\|A\| = \max_{j, k} |a_{jk} |$, which is an
"explicit expression" of the operator norm in terms of the
elements of the matrix $A$.

Comment: Thanks Martin, it is clear and I got what it wants.

Comment: @user131605: You are welcome!